# ElasticSearch Query aggregations per @timestamp hour

Tags: elasticsearch

im making a Query on elasticSearch, of metricbeat, to rate the most used process per hourly, in these moment i'm aggregating per process start time, and process name, i need to "divide" these groups using  field "@timestamp" hourly

that's my actual query

```
GET metricbeat*/_search?
{"query": {
          "bool": {
                "must": [
                    { "wildcard" : { "beat.hostname" : "ibmcx*" }},
                    { "range": {
                      "@timestamp": {
                        "gte": "2019-03-22T00:00:00",
                        "lte": "2019-03-23T00:00:00"}}},
                    {"terms" : { "beat.hostname" : ["ibmcxapp101", "ibmcxapp102", "ibmcxapp103",
                                    "ibmcxapp104", "ibmcxapp105", "ibmcxapp106", "ibmcxapp107",
                                    "ibmcxapp108", "ibmcxapp109", "ibmcxapp110", "ibmcxapp111",
                                    "ibmcxapp112", "ibmcxapp113", "ibmcxapp114", "ibmcxapp115",
                                    "ibmcxapp116", "ibmcxapp117", "ibmcxapp118", "ibmcxapp119",
                                    "ibmcxapp120", "ibmcxapp121", "ibmcxapp122", "ibmcxxaa100",
                                    "ibmcxxaa101", "ibmcxxaa102", "ibmcxxaa103", "ibmcxxaa104",
                                    "ibmcxxaa105", "ibmcxxaa106", "ibmcxxaa107", "ibmcxxaa108",
                                    "ibmcxxaa109", "ibmcxxaa110", "ibmcxxaa111", "ibmcxxaa112",
                                    "ibmcxxaa201", "ibmcxxaa202", "ibmcxxaa203", "ibmcxxaa204"
                                    ] }},
                    {"exists": {"field": "system.process.cmdline"}}
                ],
                "must_not": [
                   {"term" : { "system.process.username" : "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM" }},
                   {"term" : { "system.process.username" : "NT AUTHORITY\\NETWORK SERVICE" }},
                   {"term" : { "system.process.username" : "NT AUTHORITY\\LOCAL SERVICE" }},
                   {"term" : { "system.process.username" : "NT AUTHORITY\\Servicio de red"}},
                   {"term" : { "system.process.username" : "" }}
                  ]
          }
        },
        "size": 0,
        "aggs": {
          "group_by_start_time": {
            "terms": {
              "field": "system.process.cpu.start_time"
            },
            "aggs": {
              "group_by_name": {
                "terms": {
                  "field": "system.process.name.keyword"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "size": 0,
        "sort" : [
            { "system.process.cpu.start_time" : {"order" : "asc"}},
            { "@timestamp" : {"order" : "asc"}},
            { "system.process.pid" : {"order" : "desc"}}
        ]}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are running into?

Comment: this Query aggregate all files of a process in rage of a day, i need separate these per hourly in "@timestamp"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hard to follow and reproduce — a minimal example (I think the entire `query` is not really needed) and sample docs would go a long way.

If you want to have an hourly aggregation, the first thing you'll need to do is that aggregation and then run the others inside.

The minimal example for an hourly aggregation would be:

```
POST /metricbeat*/_search?size=0
{
    "aggs" : {
        "metrics_per_hour" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "@timestamp",
                "interval" : "hour"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Folding in the other aggregation would look like this:

```
POST /metricbeat*/_search?size=0
{
    "aggs" : {
        "metrics_per_hour" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "@timestamp",
                "interval" : "hour"
            },
            "aggs" : {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS: If you are using a daily index pattern, you could just use the right day instead of the wildcard one and then skip this part of the query:

```
"range": {
    "@timestamp": {
        "gte": "2019-03-22T00:00:00",
        "lte": "2019-03-23T00:00:00"
    }
}
```